# Elasticsearch search on _source fields are not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document in the elastic-search 5, as follow

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "json",
  "_id": "document_id",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "message": "{\"the_id\": \"custom_id\", \"more\": \"Data\"}",
    "type": "json",
    "the_id": "custom_id",
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-03T13:31:39.995Z",
    "port": 48038,
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

When I am querying using Kibana console for **_id** as follow, It is working fine and getting the record

```
 GET _search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "_id": "document_id" }} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But if I am querying for _source level field, in this case **the_id**, not getting any result.

```
 GET _search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "the_id": "custom_id" }} 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make sure I always able to query to _source level.

Comment: What's the mapping of your `the_id` field? Is it a `text` field or a `keyword` field?

Comment: Did you try `{ "term":  { "_source.the_id": "custom_id" }}`

Comment: I tried { "term": { "_source.the_id": "custom_id" }}, did not worked.

Comment: I have not created any mapping. The logstash is generating the data.Basically it is converting message field, which is json itself to a json under _source.

Comment: @sudhanshu Can you just replace `the_id` with `the_id.keyword` in your second query and check the results? I would further suggest you to read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query)

Comment: Thanks a lot @avr the_id.keyword worked great, but can you let me know the reason

Comment: @sudhanshu It's `Analyzer` which modified your original value of `the_id` field. When you index a string field(e.g `the_id`) into elasticsearch, it will create a _text_ (`the_id`) field and a _keyword_ (`the_id.keyword`) field where former contains **analyzed version** of your `the_id` value and latter contains **exact value**. Finally `term` query tries to match with **exact value** you provided in query. If your are still unclear then please read following section **Why doesn’t the term query match my document?** in link provided in previous comment.

Comment: great !! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As default mapping used in this case, elasticsearch creates multi-fields( `the_id` and `the_id.keyword`) for your `the_id` field. Here `the_id` will be created with `text` type mapping and `the_id.keyword` will be created with `keyword` type mapping.

As term queries match against `exact value` of the field, you have to provide `the_id.keyword` in your query.

To read more about it read the section **Why doesn’t the term query match my document?** in official docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query)